# Search people on facebook by name and get fields=name, id, education

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to create a search engine, it want to search people by name and i needed fields: id, name, education.

Is there possible?

I use this way:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=tom&type=user&fields=id,name,education&access_token=XXX
```

but, in result missing the education info.

```
{    "data": [
      {
         "id": "123456789",
         "name": "name0"
      },
      {
         "id": "123456789",
         "name": "name1"
      },
      {
         "id": "123456789",
         "name": "name2"
      },
      {
         "id": "123456789",
         "name": "name3"
      }, ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That´s not possible, you can only get the education of users who authorized your App with the `user_education_history` permission, this would be the API call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=education
```